# How to align something inside an <a>?

Tags: html, css

I have a very good menu right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y9jbQ/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="nav first">
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
                <li>Menu 3</li>
                <li>Menu 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

the problem is now, let's say I want a right-arrow image, aligned to right in case when there's an other sub menu. Putting  inside  isn't healthy thing. I don't want to create anything to copy 's behaviour. So,

```
<li><a href="/something"><div float left><div float right></a></li>
```

is not a good way.

Comment: added actual code for easier reading, in case jsfiddle goes away and per the faq

Answer (score 2):

Use a *[CSS Child Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)*:

```
ul.root > li > a { /* css declarations */ }
```

This will only apply the rules to the direct descendants of the root `ul` element.

---

**Illustration:**

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><!-- MATCH --></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><!-- MATCH --></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><!-- NO MATCH --></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: seems OK, but I dont see the connection.

Comment: attempts to select (only) the elements you want.  put the `align:right` or whatever where the answer has `/*css declarations */`